# Elements do not stay centered when I set breakpoints in CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid

I am currently trying to learn how to set breakpoints correctly. For example, when trying to make the footer and main wider as the browser gets wider, both elements jump to the right at once instead of staying centered. Can someone explain why this happens?

I suspect that I made a mistake in building the div's and now the media queries are not accessing the elements correctly.

```
<body>
    <h1>Your Quiz App Profile</h1>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
        <p>
          About Me.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Adipisci similique deleniti aperiam! Vitae quae nulla harum mollitia
          placeat. Ipsa ab consequatur distinctio totam commodi unde doloribus a
          quae ipsam incidunt. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
          adipisicing elit. Facere id cum iste vero magni earum repudiandae
          temporibus molestias illum assumenda? Architecto fugiat ipsam
          repudiandae eligendi pariatur quis facere nostrum similique!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="myName">My Name</div>
      <div class="profilePicture">Profile Picture</div>
      <div class="icon1">#HTML</div>
      <div class="icon2">#CSS</div>
      <div class="icon3">#JavaScript</div>
      <div class="icon4">#Git</div>
      <div class="footerclass">
        <footer>
          <p>Footer</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And heres my CSS to it:

```
* {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
  grid-template-rows: 150px 300px 200px 150px 150px;
  gap: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 2fr));

  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header picture"
    "main main main main"
    "main main main main"
    "icon icon icon icon"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: rgb(87, 235, 28);
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

.main {
  background-color: hsl(168, 76%, 42%);
  grid-area: main;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  height: auto%;
}

.main > p {
  padding: 1em;
}

.myName {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  grid-area: header;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.profilePicture {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: rgb(115, 106, 123);
  grid-area: footer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon1 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
}

.icon2 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
}

.icon3 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
}

.icon4 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footerclass {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30em;
  height: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

footer > p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .footerclass {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should maybe adjust the .container class grid-template-columns: minmax to be wider. for example as below :

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(520px, 2fr));
```

2. remove/comment .container class grid-template-rows: 150px 300px 200px 150px 150px;

```
/*grid-template-rows: 150px 300px 200px 150px 150px;*/
```

3. remove .footerclass width and replace with grid-area:footer

```
grid-area: footer;
```

4)remove/comment .footerclass 'position: absolute;'

```
/*position: absolute;*/
```

now if you expand your window to wide screen, it should be in centered as intended.

[image: adjusted]

Full edited as follow :

```css
* {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
  /*grid-template-rows: 150px 300px 200px 150px 150px;*/  /* comment here */
  gap: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(520px, 2fr));

  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header picture"
    "main main main main"
    "main main main main"
    "icon icon icon icon"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: rgb(87, 235, 28);
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

.main {
  background-color: hsl(168, 76%, 42%);
  grid-area: main;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  height: auto%;
}

.main > p {
  padding: 1em;
}

.myName {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  grid-area: header;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.profilePicture {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: rgb(115, 106, 123);
  grid-area: footer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon1 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
}

.icon2 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
}

.icon3 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
}

.icon4 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 117, 235);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 6rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footerclass {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-items: center;
  grid-area: footer; /* remove footer width and replace with grid-area:footer*/
  height: 10rem;
  /*position: absolute;*/   /* comment here */
  bottom: 0;
}

footer > p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .footerclass {
    min-width: 600px;
}
}
```

```html
 <h1>Your Quiz App Profile</h1>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
        <p>
          About Me.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Adipisci similique deleniti aperiam! Vitae quae nulla harum mollitia
          placeat. Ipsa ab consequatur distinctio totam commodi unde doloribus a
          quae ipsam incidunt. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
          adipisicing elit. Facere id cum iste vero magni earum repudiandae
          temporibus molestias illum assumenda? Architecto fugiat ipsam
          repudiandae eligendi pariatur quis facere nostrum similique!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="myName">My Name</div>
      <div class="profilePicture">Profile Picture</div>
      <div class="icon1">#HTML</div>
      <div class="icon2">#CSS</div>
      <div class="icon3">#JavaScript</div>
      <div class="icon4">#Git</div>
      <div class="footerclass">
        <footer>
          <p>Footer</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems that cause unexpected layout.

1. The `grid-template-columns` is declared twice, so the last one will override the first one. `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 2fr))` is the reason why the grid items flow to the right.
2. The position of `footerclass` is `absolute`, so this class will be out of normal flow. Instead, you should put it back in the grid so it will follow the original grid template.
3. The media query forces the width of `footerclass` to 600px when viewport is wider than 768px. This will also override the original style of `footerclass`, which is supposed to be part of grid.

The change points are listed below.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 300px 200px 150px 150px;
  gap: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));

  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header picture"
    "main main main main"
    "main main main main"
    "icon icon icon icon"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

.main {
  background-color: hsl(168, 76%, 42%);
  grid-area: main;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.footer {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: rgb(115, 106, 123);
  text-align: center;
}

.footerclass {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: footer;
}

/* 
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .footerclass {
    width: 600px;
  }
} */
```

***Explanation***

1. We use `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))` to distribute the column width equally.
2. Remove `position: absolute` from `footerclass` to bring it back to grid template
3. Move the `grid-area: footer` to `footerclass` instead of its child element `footer`
4. Comment out the media query so the `footerclass` can grow and shrink as wide as the viewport.

You may consider reusing the media query to adjust the `font-size` or `grid-template` for both large and small screens.

***Layout after revision***

[image: css-grid]